Could some version of a "most factually incorrect quantitative finance wrong answers from AI" question be on-topic?
I've been pondering whether some version of this question might be on-topic. One question and AI response per answer, communty wiki flag and an explanation of why the AI response is wrong would be encouraged. The AI program does not need to be identified.
I think this is likely to be useful and educational - not just entertaining.
Please tell me if you think this discussion might be problematic / inappropriate, or if you see a better way of asking this, or have other comments.

I think given the increased use of chat bot AIs this sort of thing might becoming more in scope. We have to move with the times.
